# Node.js + Bluebird + csv: extra item [object Object]

Tags: node.js, csv, promise, bluebird

I have the following code for downloading csv files:

```
function download_csv(symbol) {
    var req_url = url + '&s=' + symbol
    var filename = '/prices/' + symbol + '.csv'

    return request.getAsync(req_url)
    .then(function(resp) {
        fs.writeFileAsync(filename, resp)
    })
}

Promise.map(symbols, download_csv, {concurrency: 128})
.error(function(e) {console.error('error ocurred: ', e.message)})
.done(function() {console.log('done')})
```

When I open the csv file, the first row is shifted right by 1 column:

```
[object Object] Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close
```

The first column should say Date, not [object Object]. What is the error in my code?

Comment: Chances are you're using a library that returns multiple values and promisifying it puts the results in an array, what does `console.log` show for `resp` in the `.then` after `getAsync` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is an array of `[response, body]` which you can `.spread`:

```
function download_csv(symbol) {
    var req_url = url + '&s=' + symbol
    var filename = '/prices/' + symbol + '.csv'

    return request.getAsync(req_url).spread(function(response, body) {
        // Also add return statement here, very important
        return fs.writeFileAsync(filename, body)
    })
}
```

This is because the callback signature is:

```
callback(err, response, body)
```

Comment: why do I need a return in front of fs.writeFileSync?

Comment: @tldr so that the promises form a chain where the next then is not called until the first completes. If you have no return then you have 2 problems:

Comment: @tldr 1. The `Promise.map` can fulfill before any file is actually even written. With return, it only fulfills once all files are actually written successfully.

Comment: @tldr 2. If a file write fails, it will cause unhandled error, the `.error()` won't catch it. And the map continues to write other files too